# putting a new command inside a function, and how to cut decimals of list comrpise of .ndarray

Tags: python

I wrote this script, which appends 2 arrays into array c:

```
a=np.arange(1,5,0.3252)
b=np.arange(2,5,.3252)

c=[]
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

I want to make all floats in "c" to be with .2f after decimal.

### Update

I tried again the join command and it worked:

```
for i in c:
a=[]
b=' '.join("%.2f" % value for value in i)
a.append(b)
print a
```

I assume there is a shorter way to code it

@memoselyk

Comment: You are not using python 3 are you?

Comment: true, my bad... @memoselyk 

i uploaded the problem more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are dealing with `numpy` arrays, the selections is as simple as this.

Assuming you have the following data, for demonstration purposes only 3 columns:

```
Id = np.arange(5, dtype=float)
Le = np.linspace(.1, .5, 5, dtype=float)
Az = np.linspace(5, 25, 5, dtype=float)

Measurements = np.column_stack((Id, Le, Az))

>>> Measurements
array([[  0. ,   0.1,   5. ],
       [  1. ,   0.2,  10. ],
       [  2. ,   0.3,  15. ],
       [  3. ,   0.4,  20. ],
       [  4. ,   0.5,  25. ]])
```

and you want to select the following range,

```
a = 10
b = 20
```

You can leverage, `numpy`'s [indexing capabilities](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) and provide it with a boolean mask:

```
selection = Measurements[(a <= Az) & (Az <= b)]

# array([[  1. ,   0.2,  10. ],
#        [  2. ,   0.3,  15. ],
#        [  3. ,   0.4,  20. ]])
```

If you really need the indexes, you can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where).

```
>>> np.where((a <= Az) & (Az <= b))
(array([1, 2, 3]),)
```

For the printing part, you could leverage [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to control the precision with `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)`. Or set a custom formatter for floats like:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind': lambda v: "%.2f" % v)
```

---

*First answer*

> TypeError: float argument required, not list

It's telling you that you passed a list as the value to be converted.

Which is *not* surprising since you defined `final_values` using list comprehension.

To print all float values from `final_values` using the `'%.2f'` format specifier you need to

```
print ' '.join("%.2f" % value for value in final_values)
```

That is, converting each value separately and then assembling a single string separating them with spaces.

Comment: thanks for the help,

not surprising indeed, but after running print ' '.join command, all  i got in the output is 
%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f

as it ran over the variables in the list and replaced them with "%.2f"

@memoselyk

Comment: @nadav_n, My bad, the intention was to do string interpolation on each value, that's amended now.

Comment: ok thats a good correction, now i'm getting somewhere!

i ran the script again, but it came with an error:
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray.

this is how the data is defined:
type(final_values) =  list
type(final_values[0] = nd.array

when i tried to run the line with print ' '.join("%.2f" % value for value in final_values[0]) , it really did return the 1st line of final_values and with only 2 decimals as it should! so it did cheered me up a bit, but i need to find a way for it to print all the lines in final_values. 

@memoselyk

Answer (score 0):

in your function `row_pick` is not necessary to iterate over the whole list to get your desire sub list, and even if you have to, you can stop when `i>=b` to avoid unnecessary iterations, but a slice is enough, check this:

```
>>> c=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
>>> a=2
>>> b=5
>>> c[a+1:b]
[400, 500]
```

if you want the index, enumerate also accept a second argument to indicate it from where start to enumerate and you can do something like this

```
>>> [(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(c[a+1:b],a+1)]
[(400, 3), (500, 4)]
>>> c[3]
400
>>> c[4]
500
>>> list(range(a+1,b))
[3, 4]
>>>
```